# My addition of data in firebase database is replacing the existing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in React js .This is my addition to the database.But data is getting overwritten each time.i want that the unique id can have multiple child(download URL) .But on each addition the previous child(Download URL) is replaced

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( 
    (downloadURL)=> {
     
        
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + localStorage.getItem('key')).set({
           downloadURL:downloadURL
          });
```

[image: i want that the downloadURL is not replaced each time]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  What specifically do you think should happen instead of what you observe?

Comment: You need an array, not a string. Or create another collection with userId and download url in it.

Comment: Sir can you explain where can i specify it as an array and how to push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the following db:

```
users
  randomId
    downloadUrl : url
    downloadUrl1 : url
```

Then you need to increment the `downloadUrl` attribute. Currently it is getting overwritten because it's always the same name. For example:

```
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + localStorage.getItem('key')).update({
         downloadUrl1:downloadURL
          });
```

Comment: Sir i changed the name just to check but it is still replacing downloadURL

Comment: did you get `downloadUrl1` in the database?

Comment: yes sir,now it is working fine,just have to make different names

Comment: how can i make different names on each run